# Is there a way to ensure that an object is always displayed on top of another with no overlaps?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender, cg, shaderlab

I'm having some issues with items of clothing on an avatar as you can see in the image below

[image: Image 1]

Most would suggest that i simply pull the trousers away from the body within the modelling software which is fine until it is combined with other items of clothing

[image: Image 2]

I could now pull the shirt away from the trousers but I have many different items of clothing and to check/adjust each of them does not seem like the way to go.

It would be better to try and apply some sort of layering system.

Can anyone advise me on how i may be able to achieve such a system or a how i can achieve the results I am aiming for?

I have already looked into trying to do this using shaders but had no luck achieving the result I'm trying to get (but admittedly I am no Shaderlab/CG expert)

I have also tried separating the avatar into different pieces and replacing them with the clothing meshes but this still leaves the problem of the clothing being visible through each other.

I would like to preferably have some sort of system where i can layer each item of clothing so that no matter what they display on top of each other in the correct order without any overlaps.

Comment: Many games will completely replace naked legs with trouser-legs, instead of trying to render legs and trousers at the same time.   Similarly, for the shirt, you can swap out the entire torso for a shirt-and-arms mesh.

Comment: Thank you Leo. I will be trying this now as i think this needs to be resolved at the modelling level and not the rendering level. trying to fix it at the rendering level is creating some issues when running some of the animations.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use layering you can use Unity's [Render Layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) which are actually made for that.

1. Go to Layers -> Edit Layers

   [image]
2. Add the Layers you want (the order doesn't matter)

   [image]
3. Asign the Layers to the objects you want to be rendered by a ceratin camera.

   [image]

   as an example I added a `trousers cube` with layer `trousers`, a `pillover cube` with layer `pullover` and a `OnTop cube` with layer `OnTop`
4. Create a new Empty GameObject and call it e.g. `CameraParent`. This will contain all your cameras and you should move this one instead of the camera you moved so far.

   In case this is a VR/AR app you might have to attach a `Camera` component to this parent object, make it the main camera but make it not render anything

   [image]
5. Create e.g. 4 Child objects and give them a `Camera` component. Also make sure only one Camera is tagged as `MainCamera` and only one has an `AudioListener` in your Scene. I used 4 cameras as example to have a `TrousersCamera` a `PulloverCamera` an `OnTopCamera` and a `BackgroundCamera`.
6. Now the setup for the rendering

   - BackgroundCamera
     Here you render anything else like you did before

     - `ClearFlags`: e.g. `SkyBox`
     - `Culling Mask`: select all Layers **except** `trousers`, `pullover` and `OnTop`
     - `Depth`: `-1`
   - TrousersCamera
     For rendering the trousers (on top of anything else)

     - `ClearFlags`: Depth only
     - `Culling Mask`: select **only** `trousers`
     - `Depth`: `0` (you see a bigger value is rendered on top of a lower value)
   - PulloverCamera
     For rendering the pullover on top of the trousers

     - `ClearFlags`: Depth only
     - `Culling Mask`: select **only** `pullover`
     - `Depth`: `1`
   - OnTopCamera
     For rendering something else on top of everything

     - `ClearFlags`: Depth only
     - `Culling Mask`: select **only** `OnTop`
     - `Depth`: `2`

   [image]

As result you can see that though the red cube (`OnTop cube`) is really far behind the rest and the blue cube (`Pullover cube`) in the middle, the red one will allways be rendered on top, than the blue, than the brown (`trousers cube`) and finally the background.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed explanation. I thought about doing this but didn't think it would work as the avatar contains a variety of animations where the hand may move infront of the top for example. Either way, I did it to test it out and it seems i was correct. We end up with undesired results with some animations. [Image](https://ibb.co/CmQXBFK) I may try Leo's suggestion (above) and see how that goes. The model will have a variety of clothing items and animations so maybe this needs to be resolved at the modelling level rather than the rendering level - still open to ideas